# Is there anything wrong with creating an XML feed this way?

Tags: php, xml, coding-style, simplexml, domdocument

This is a fragment of code from one of my projects, I have looked up ways to creating XML documents with php and found suggestions to use SimpleXMLElement or DOMDocument but is there anything wrong with the below approach? it seems much more simple.

Note: the whole point of this question is to get the pros and cons of each approach even though all of them will work.

```
public function getXML() {

    $sc = function($str) {
        return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
    };

    $XMLString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'
            . '<playlist>'
            . '<id>' . $sc($this->getID()) . '</id>'
            . '<title>' . $sc($this->getTitle()) . '</title>'
            . '<description>' . $sc($this->getDescription()) . '</description>'
            . '<numVideos>' . $sc($this->getNumOfVideos()) . '</numVideos>';
    foreach ($this->videoList as $v) {
        $XMLString.= '<video>'
                . '<id>' . $sc($v->getID()) . '</id>'
                . '<title>' . $sc($v->getTitle()) . '</title>'
                . '<duration>' . $sc($v->getDuration()) . '</duration>'
                . '<thumbnail>' . $sc($v->getThumbnail()) . '</thumbnail>'
                . '<datePublished>' . $sc($v->getDatePublished()) . '</datePublished>'
                . '<description>' . $sc($v->getDescription()) . '</description>'
                . '<views>' . $sc($v->getViews()) . '</views>'
                . '<favorites>' . $sc($v->getFavorites()) . '</favorites>'
                . '<numRated>' . $sc($v->getNumRaters()) . '</numRated>'
                . '<author>' . $sc($v->getAuthor()) . '</author>'
                . '</video>';
    }
    $XMLString.= "</playlist>";

    return $XMLString
}
```

Verses

```
public function getXML() {

    $sc = function($str) {
        return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
    };
    $playlist = new SimpleXMLElement("<playlist></playlist>");
    $playlist->addChild("id", $sc($this->getID()));
    $playlist->addChild("title", $sc($this->getTitle()));
    $playlist->addChild("description", $sc($this->getDescription()));
    $playlist->addChild("numVideos", $sc($this->getNumOfVideos()));
    foreach ($this->videoList as $k => $v) {
        $videos = $playlist->addChild("videos");
        $videos->addChild('id', $sc($v->getID()));
        $videos->addChild('title', $sc($v->getTitle()));
        $videos->addChild('duration', $sc($v->getDuration()));
        $videos->addChild('thumbnail', $sc($v->getThumbnail()));
        $videos->addChild('datePublished', $sc($v->getDatePublished()));
        $videos->addChild('description', $sc($v->getDescription()));
        $videos->addChild('views', $sc($v->getViews()));
        $videos->addChild('favorites', $sc($v->getFavorites()));
        $videos->addChild('numRated', $sc($v->getNumRaters()));
        $videos->addChild('author', $sc($v->getAuthor()));
    }


    return $playlist->asXML();
}
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with anything works ok for you.

Comment: @Dagon Thinking "it work, no need to improve it" may be bad IMHO, using SimpleXMLElement is simple as what he did

Comment: That looks fine. Outputting XML is the same as outputting HTML; there is no reason to build a DOM just to output it.

Comment: to old,busy and depressed to bother with anything other than "it works, move on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be difficult to read and maintain if you, or better yet -- another developer,  ever need to have nested elements and multiple children.

Comment: agreed its much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your values so that characters like `<`, `"`, etc. will not break your xml:

```
htmlspecialchars($v->getTitle(), ENT_QUOTES)
```

etc.